# How to solve this aggregation with MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection *lineups* some relevant properties for my post:

- `players`, being an array,
- `round`, being a number,
- `team`, being an string.

I need then to know:

> *How many same team documents with round 2 got players array empty and any same team document with round 1 got a not empty players array?.*

Telling more about my schema:

- There are multiple lineups with distinct teams.
- There are multiple lineups with distinct round and same team.

Input and output examples:

In this very simple case where got only 4 documents of 2 teams:

```
{team: "goats", players: ['3', '4', '3'], matchDate: {round: 1}}
{team: "eagles", players: ['3', '4', '3'], matchDate: {round: 1}}
{team: "goats", players: [], matchDate: {round: 2}}
{team: "eagles" ,players: [], matchDate: {round: 2}}
```

As:

- Round 2 eagles doc got not players and same eagles team at round 1 got players.
- Round 2 goats doc got not players and same goats team at round 1 got players.

And for the next modified example, the expected query result would be 1:

```
{team: "goats", players: ['3', '4', '3'], matchDate: {round: 1}}
{team: "eagles", players: ['3', '4', '3'], matchDate: {round: 1}}
{team: "goats", players: [], matchDate: {round: 2}}
{team: "eagles" ,players: ['2','8'], matchDate: {round: 2}}
```

As:

- Only goats team got not players at round 2 and did get players at round 1.

**How could I retrieve that information?**

I just started trying with an aggregation but this is all I got so far:

```
db.lineup.aggregate([
  {$match: {"matchDate.round": {$lte: 2}}},
  {$group: {_id: "$team", lineups: {$push: "$players"}}}
])
```

Comment: This is really unclear. What is supposed to be aggregated here? Is players already and array or is it not? You say *"The next modified docs"*, what does that mean? Why would there be different results? Your attempt show "searchableName", yet there is no such field in your example data. So, show some sample data at the source, show the expected result and take some time to describe the "logic". Which should also lead to a better title to the question. Too obtuse. You need to be more to the point.

Comment: I edited the question a bit explaining that its a *modified example* I wanted to offer a really simple example of docs. Players is actually an array with objects inside but the point is that **it's an array** and **it can be empty or not**

Comment: Sorry nothing here that is solvable. Take more that just a few minutes to consider the comment and ask yourself *"If someone showed this to me, and I had no other knowledge of what the data really looked like or the problem to be solved then is it enough for me to find a solution from"*. I see no edited explaination ( last edit 4 minutes ago, and your comment is 2 minutes old ), and really no clear problem statement of what you are trying to do. A clear example would be, "this list of things", I need to get "this output" with "these rules". And the rules clearly define what is shown output.

Comment: @BlakesSeven tell me if this is enough, I offered a very simple `players` case as it only matters if its empty or not

Comment: This is still "really unclear what you are asking" ( why it does not have an answer ). I can "presume" that all you mean by your *"next modified example"* is that you just expect that to match as well because one array in round 2 is empty. But there are still so many questions. 1. How do we get this list of four in the first place? 2. I presume they are mean to be "paired" in some way, how do you know this? 3. The further presumtion is you want to "pair up" more data than just this sample, therefore explain the case. I ask so you can "think" about it and revise if you want someone to answer.

Comment: Believe me. This is not unanswered because "no one knows how to do it", it is unanswered because no-one really understands what the question really is. I suspect here that this design for you "actual" use case here, ( which you don't explain ) is flawed and will not get you the correct or efficient results. Sit down and take the time to properly explain your "use case" in full. Asking further questions on this model is not productive until you resolve the basic issue first.