# How to ensure MongoDB update performance for a non _id matching query?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I got a production API and MongoDB database for which I'm performing updates  against a collection in this fashion (mongo shell syntax representation):

```
db.lineups.update({_id: <some_object_id>}, <some_update>);
```

Lineups collection got this relevant fields:

- `players`, being an array of objects
- `matchDate`, being an object with a `round` property being a number
- `team`, being an string

Now I need to use other update to this:

```
db.lineup.upate({team: <team_string_id>, 'matchDate.round': {$gte: <any_integer>}}, <update_object>)
```

So I need to figure out how this could affect update and general performance on the database and how I can cope it.

Would a compound index like `{team: true, "matchDate.round": true}` help?

To extend explanation on the schema design, following sentences apply for my collection:

- *There are multiple `lineup` docs with same single team.*
- *Above is because, there are multiple `lineup docs with distinct`matchDate.round` with the same team.*
- *In a single sentence: 'a team got multiple lineups for each match date round.'*

A sample document would be:

```
{
  players: [{name: "Ramos", number: 4}, {name: "James", number: 10}, {name: "Isco", number: 23}],
  matchDate: {round: 3, date: new Date()},
  team: "key-real-madrid"
}
```

Comment: It would be best if you could show us a sample document.

Comment: @ZeMoon editing now ...

Comment: I would go back and pay attention to your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31954171/how-to-solve-this-aggregation-with-mongodb) as you are almost certainly headed down the wrong track with your design, for the goals you want to achieve.

Comment: @BlakesSeven I can edit now the post u are refering, I can offer all needed information if you want to. I'm not fan of the present schema design but I that's what I got to work with now. Any coping or possible improves are welcomed too :)